# How to count total entries in an array, and display the sum total in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have some code that processes an array of values, each one with a value 1 or 0.

```
<?php
$GD_album = [
[$gdclock,1],
[$gdheart,1],
[$gdblue,1],
[$gdblack5th,0],
[$gdgreymarble,1],
[$gdblack7th,0]
];

$GD[have] = '';
foreach($GD_album as list($name, $own)) {if ($own === 1)echo $name;}
echo $GD[have];
?>
```

Each of my $gd*** variables draws a block of PHP and HTML code, and the foreach I have above will only draw the ones with a "1", and skip the ones with a 0. This works great.

What I'd like to do is have a piece of code that will add up each variable with a value of 1; for a total of 4. I'd also like some code to add up 0; for a total of 2. Then I would like to add those two results together for a total of 6.

I have tried the count() and array_sum() functions with little success. What I tried that gave me some results is:

```
<?php
$GD[h_total] = '';
    foreach($GD_album as list($name, $own))
    {if ($own === 1) echo count($own);}
echo $GD[h_total];
?>

<?php
$GD[w_total] = '';
    foreach($GD_album as list($name, $own))
    {if ($own === 0) echo count($own);}
echo $GD[w_total];
?>
```

This however, only outputs: "1111" and not "4". And "00", not "2", respectively. Ideally, some code that could count my 0's & 1's, also add them, and stylize as "Have 4/6" or "Need 2/6" would be best! Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: `This however, only outputs: "1111" and not "4". And "00", not "2"` isn't the literal character count of those, added together, 6?

Answer (score 0):

**Try the code below:**

```php
<?php

$GD_album = [
['gdclock',1],
['gdheart',1],
['gdblue',1],
['gdblack5th',0],
['gdgreymarble',1],
['gdblack7th',0]
];

$GD['h_total'] = [];
foreach($GD_album as list($name, $own)){
    if(isset($GD['h_total'][$own])){
        $GD['h_total'][$own]++;
    }else{
        $GD['h_total'][$own] = 1;
    }
}
    
echo 'total zeros: '. $GD['h_total'][0];
echo 'total ones: '. $GD['h_total'][1];
echo 'total: ' .array_sum($GD['h_total']);
```

The output:

```php
total zeros: 2
total ones: 4
total: 6
```